# Is it possible to store the same string multiple times in a arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to store a lot of small strings in a arraylist.
It is possible to store the same string twice?

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("string1");
    list.add("string2");
    list.add("string1");
    list.add("string3");
```

System.out.println(list); should then give: [string1, string2, string1, string3]

Comment: Yes I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: @user1637234 Show us the exact code that isn't working. Your current example does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to store the same string multiple times in a arraylist?

Yes

> `System.out.println(list);` should then give: [string1, string2, string1, string3]

It does.

Comment: It seems that is was indeed a problem with the original code. Sorry for the trouble.